# Do Thai 'state quarantine' facilities (SQ) provide wifi?

Tags: covid-19, thailand, wifi, quarantine

In Thailand, the government mandates a 14 day quarantine of all foreign travellers wanting to enter the country. They offer [state quarantine](http://www.xinhuanet.com/english/2020-09/02/c_139337934.htm) (SQ) and [alternative state quarantine](https://thaiest.com/blog/list-of-alternative-state-quarantine-asq-hotels-thailand) (ASQ). The latter is run by hotels which offer complimentary wifi and other service.

Does the state quarantine (SQ) guarantee (free) wifi as well? I'm looking for an official source (if they do guarantee it), because there are so many different facilities from hotels to military bases that it's not clear if there is such a guarantee. Of course, to answer the question in the negative only really needs one example of there being no wifi.

Comment: While they will probably try to offer it (seems a quite desirable feature for a place where you are going to intern lots of foreigners), I doubt they would "guarantee" it. Suppose they fill all the SQ they already have (or for any other reason) and need to open a new one. They probably have a list of requisites and other nice-to-haves. Plus likely a budget. Coulld they house that people in a place with no water? Absolutely not! Could they house them in a place with no WiFi (or an absurdly slow one)? Well, yes.

Comment: @Ángel the SQ facilities are for Thai nationals only (paid for by the state). Foreigners (and Thais willing to pay) can use the alternative facilities of their choosing (nice hotels which offer package deals that include medical services). For the SQ, I've seen military barracks which didn't look so comfortable (and not sure about the wifi), but I've heard a lot of stories about okay hotels too. I figure if there's wifi, I can do some work to pass the time even if the surroundings aren't as nice.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.